# cef project compile link error2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, chromium-embedded

I have downloaded the cef_binary_3.2840.1493.g4e029f4_windows32 to start my project with CEF.After I use cmake to build VS project,I use the VS2015 to compile the cef project(cef_simple),But it seems have some link error like this:
void __cdecl base::allocator::InsertAllocatorDispatch(struct base::allocator::AllocatorDispatch *)" (?InsertAllocatorDispatch@allocator@base@@YAXPAUAllocatorDispatch@12@@Z)    cefsimple   D:\cef\cefsimple\cef_sandbox.lib(malloc_dump_provider.obj)
And it make me confused because others can compile and run it successfully(his system is WIN10 64 with VS2013),so anybody can give me answer?
PS:my system is WIN7 64

Answer (score 1):

workaround:
delete the string ../../debug/cef_sandbox.lib. (in project settings->Linker->input->AdditionalDependencies)
and also need delete in Defines: CEF_USE_SANDBOX

P.S. This problem described in 'https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial' and in comments of cefsimple_win.cc file. Reason of this error: cef_sandbox.lib linked in VS2013 and in new version VS it doesn't link. Another solution would be to use: 
-DUSE_SANDBOX=OFF when running Cmake